# Layout change depending on number of posts within a widget

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

Ok so I am going to try and explain this the best I can. I created a widget that will pull in a featured image from the post on the home page based on the category. Right now it pulls in 4 posts. I would like to have the option to pull in 2, 3, 4, or 6 posts. I would also like to change the layout based on how many posts are coming in. Is it possible to only display 2, 3,4, or 6 posts and how would I go about changing the layout based on the number of posts coming in. I was thinking it would refer to a container class in the css for each number of posts or something along the lines of that. Any links, tutorials, or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
- Michael

Comment: I would create different classes, based on the number of posts. But your code will need to change the class based on the number of posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pure CSS

This provides a CSS3 method to achieve what you want, with a fall back in place for CSS2. Basically, you have a wrapper to target your post items, which will be the only children directly in that wrapper (or, at least the only children of a particular "tag" type, here a `div`). So something like the following, only the number of children can be 2, 3, 4, or 6 (as you requested).

**Simple HTML** (this does not have to be `div` elements; just illustrating)

```
<div class="postWrapper">
  <div>This is a post</div>
  <div>This is the second post</div>
</div>
```

**Set Default CSS2**

For IE7/8, this will be the *default display* no matter how many posts are being shown in those two browsers, using this selector:

```
.postWrapper > div { ... }
```

**Set Fancy CSS3**

This is doen based on number of posts and will be displayed in all CSS3 browsers. It  uses this series of selectors, ***in this order:*** (we are *using the cascade* to our advantage here):

```
.postWrapper > div:nth-last-of-type(2),
.postWrapper > div:nth-last-of-type(2) ~ div {
   ... your two display css ...
}

.postWrapper > div:nth-last-of-type(3),
.postWrapper > div:nth-last-of-type(3) ~ div {
   ... your three display css ...
}

.postWrapper > div:nth-last-of-type(4),
.postWrapper > div:nth-last-of-type(4) ~ div {
   ... your four display css ...
}

.postWrapper > div:nth-last-of-type(6),
.postWrapper > div:nth-last-of-type(6) ~ div {
   ... your six display css ...
}
```

What this is doing is utilizing the `:nth-last-of-type()` selector to "count backwards" through the number of child div's of the wrapper, apply a style to that `div`, and then use the general sibling combinator `~` to style all the other div's in `.postWrapper` that follow that (theoretical) first `div`. It does this for the first two using the `:nth-last-of-type(2)`, but then if the wrapper contains three, the next set of selectors that uses `:nth-last-of-type(3)` overrides the previous `(2)` selector, and so forth. In this way, through a series of overriding css in the cascade, we change our settings for the number of post elements.

You can see a sample of this technique for illustration purposes in [**in this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fS6Tz/3/).

**NOTE:** Because we are using the cascade to override, ***it is imperative that you make sure to handle any previously set css***. In my fiddle example, note how I put a `margin` on a group of four, but then I removed it on a group of six. If I had mentioned nothing of `margin` in group six (that is, no overriding), then elements 3-6 (but not 1-2) of the group of six would have had margin still applied based off the previous settings for the group of four.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to show me a coded example and going into detail in your explanation! Super Awesome, thank you! ~